# Finding the number of possible paths in a cave system (Python)

Tags: python, programming-challenge, recursion, iterator

I've finally come up with  working solution for day 12 of ***AdventOfCode***, where you have to find the number of possible paths in a cave system following a given set of rules (described below). My solution seems a bit messy. I include an iterator class that employs recursive call of the same iterator. I'd be very grateful if you could review this code.

First I present the verbatim of the problem, then the input, then my solution.

> With your submarine's subterranean subsystems subsisting suboptimally,
> the only way you're getting out of this cave anytime soon is by
> finding a path yourself. Not just **a** path - the only way to know if
> you've found the **best** path is to find **all** of them.
>
> Fortunately, the sensors are still mostly working, and so you build a
> rough map of the remaining caves (your puzzle input). For example:
>
> ```
> start-A
> start-b
> A-c
> A-b
> b-d
> A-end
> b-end
> ```
>
> This is a list of how all of
> the caves are connected. You start in the cave named `start`, and your
> destination is the cave named `end`. An entry like `b-d` means that cave `b`
> is connected to cave `d` - that is, you can move between them.
>
> So, the above cave system looks roughly like this:
>
> ```
>     start
>     /   \
> c--A-----b--d
>     \   /
>      end
> ```
>
> Your goal is to find the number of distinct **paths** that start at `start`, end at `end`, > and don't visit small caves more than once.
> There are two types of caves: **big** caves (written in uppercase, like `A`)
> and **small** caves (written in lowercase, like `b`). It would be a waste of
> time to visit any small cave more than once, but big caves are large
> enough that it might be worth visiting them multiple times. So, all
> paths you find should **visit small caves at most once**, and can **visit
> big caves any number of times**.
>
> Given these rules, there are `10` paths through this example cave
> system:
>
> ```
> start,A,b,A,c,A,end
> start,A,b,A,end
> start,A,b,end
> start,A,c,A,b,A,end
> start,A,c,A,b,end
> start,A,c,A,end
> start,A,end
> start,b,A,c,A,end
> start,b,A,end
> start,b,end
> ```
>
> (Each line in the above list corresponds to
> a single path; the caves visited by that path are listed in the order
> they are visited and separated by commas.)
>
> Note that in this cave system, cave `d` is never visited by any path: to
> do so, cave `b` would need to be visited twice (once on the way to cave
> `d` and a second time when returning from cave `d`), and since cave `b` is
> small, this is not allowed.
>
> Here is a slightly larger example:
>
> ```
> dc-end
> HN-start
> start-kj
> dc-start
> dc-HN
> LN-dc
> HN-end
> kj-sa
> kj-HN
> kj-dc
> ```
>
> The `19` paths through it are as follows:
>
> ```
> start,HN,dc,HN,end
> start,HN,dc,HN,kj,HN,end
> start,HN,dc,end
> start,HN,dc,kj,HN,end
> start,HN,end
> start,HN,kj,HN,dc,HN,end
> start,HN,kj,HN,dc,end
> start,HN,kj,HN,end
> start,HN,kj,dc,HN,end
> start,HN,kj,dc,end
> start,dc,HN,end
> start,dc,HN,kj,HN,end
> start,dc,end
> start,dc,kj,HN,end
> start,kj,HN,dc,HN,end
> start,kj,HN,dc,end
> start,kj,HN,end
> start,kj,dc,HN,end
> start,kj,dc,end
> ```
>
> Finally, this even
> larger example has `226` paths through it:
>
> ```
> fs-end
> he-DX
> fs-he
> start-DX
> pj-DX
> end-zg
> zg-sl
> zg-pj
> pj-he
> RW-he
> fs-DX
> pj-RW
> zg-RW
> start-pj
> he-WI
> zg-he
> pj-fs
> start-RW
> ```
>
> **How many paths through
> this cave system are there that visit small caves at most once?**
>
> Your puzzle answer was `4912`.
>
> **--- Part Two ---**
>
> After reviewing the available paths, you realize you might have time to visit a single > small cave **twice**. Specifically, big
> caves can be visited any number of times, a single small cave can be
> visited at most twice, and the remaining small caves can be visited at
> most once. However, the caves named `start` and `end` can only be visited
> **exactly once each**: once you leave the `start` cave, you may not return
> to it, and once you reach the `end` cave, the path must end immediately.
>
> Now, the `36` possible paths through the first example above are:
>
> ```
> start,A,b,A,b,A,c,A,end
> start,A,b,A,b,A,end
> start,A,b,A,b,end
> start,A,b,A,c,A,b,A,end
> start,A,b,A,c,A,b,end
> start,A,b,A,c,A,c,A,end
> start,A,b,A,c,A,end
> start,A,b,A,end
> start,A,b,d,b,A,c,A,end
> start,A,b,d,b,A,end
> start,A,b,d,b,end
> start,A,b,end
> start,A,c,A,b,A,b,A,end
> start,A,c,A,b,A,b,end
> start,A,c,A,b,A,c,A,end
> start,A,c,A,b,A,end
> start,A,c,A,b,d,b,A,end
> start,A,c,A,b,d,b,end
> start,A,c,A,b,end
> start,A,c,A,c,A,b,A,end
> start,A,c,A,c,A,b,end
> start,A,c,A,c,A,end
> start,A,c,A,end start,A,end
> start,b,A,b,A,c,A,end
> start,b,A,b,A,end
> start,b,A,b,end
> start,b,A,c,A,b,A,end
> start,b,A,c,A,b,end
> start,b,A,c,A,c,A,end
> start,b,A,c,A,end
> start,b,A,end
> start,b,d,b,A,c,A,end
> start,b,d,b,A,end
> start,b,d,b,end
> start,b,end
> ```
>
> The slightly larger example above now has `103` paths
> through it, and the even larger example now has `3509` paths through it.
>
> Given these new rules, **how many paths through this cave system are
> there?**
>
> Your puzzle answer was `150004`.

***The input:***

```
YW-end
DK-la
la-XG
end-gy
zq-ci
XG-gz
TF-la
xm-la
gy-gz
ci-start
YW-ci
TF-zq
ci-DK
la-TS
zq-YW
gz-YW
zq-gz
end-gz
ci-TF
DK-zq
gy-YW
start-DK
gz-DK
zq-la
start-TF
```

***The solution***

```
import logging

# Debug header that enables logging if `DEBUG = True`. WARNING: A huge amount of data is being logged due to the sheer
# amount of computation, enabling `DEBUG` causes this program to take 10+ to execute and creates a ~500MB text file.
DEBUG = False

logger = logging.getLogger("new_service")
logger.setLevel(logging.FATAL)
if DEBUG:
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_format = logging.Formatter("%(message)s")

log_handler = logging.FileHandler("log12.txt", mode='w')
log_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

logger.addHandler(log_handler)


class CaveSystem:
    """
    The class for keeping track of caves and their connections. Iterating through a `CaveSystem` instance results in
    a list of paths where big caves can be visited unlimited amount of times and small caves can only be visited once.
    Calling the same instance also returns an iterator, but if takes `True` as an argument, the number of paths are
    extended by including those where a single small cave is explored twice.


    Attributes:
        caves : `dict` of caves in the instance, with cave names for keys and `Cave` objects for values.
    """

    def __init__(self, puzzle):
        """
        :param puzzle: `list` of `str` representations of cave connections
        """

        # record every connection in a temporary `list` `joint`
        joints = []
        for joint in puzzle:
            joints.append(joint.split('-'))

        # extract the total amount of `caves` from `joints` and create a `Cave` object corresponding to every one of
        # them. Register each cave in the `self.caves` attribute.
        caves = set(flatten(joints))
        self.caves = {}
        for cave in caves:
            self.caves[cave] = self.Cave(cave)

        # Register every joint in each of the two corresponding `Cave` objects
        for joint in joints:
            self.caves[joint[0]].joints.append(joint[1])
            self.caves[joint[1]].joints.append(joint[0])

    def __call__(self, extend_one_small=False):
        """
        Return a `CaveIterator` that iterates through every path that can be taken in the given cave system.
        Same as `self.__iter__()` if `extend_one_small` is `False`, otherwise one single cave can be explore up to
        2 times.
        :param extend_one_small: `bool`, enables exploring one small cave up to two times in a single path.
        Default `False`
        :return: `CaveIterator`
        """
        if extend_one_small:
            return CaveIterator(self, [self.caves['start']], extend_one_small=True)
        return self.__iter__()

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Return a `CaveIterator` that iterates through every path that can be taken in the given cave system. Small
        caves can only be explored once, while large caves can be explored any amount of times.
        :return: `CaveIterator`
        """
        # Every path begins at cave 'start'
        return CaveIterator(self, [self.caves['start']])

    class Cave:
        """
        This nested class can only be used by the outer class and serves to store every cave within the same outer class

        Attributes:
            name : `str` the name of the cave. Capital letters designate large caves, and lowercase letters
            designate small caves

            big : `bool`, `True` if the cave is big, `False` otherwise

            joints : `list` of `str`, listing every cave name that is connected to this one
        """

        def __init__(self, name):
            """
            :param name: `str` name of the cave. Capital letters designate the cave as being large, otherwise the cave
            is considered small
            """
            self.name = name
            self.big = False
            if self.name.lower() != self.name:
                self.big = True

            # Since only the name of the cave is supplied to the constructor, it is up to the outer class to fill this
            # in
            self.joints = []


class CaveIterator:
    """
    A recursive iterator that goes deeper and deeper into recursion until it finds the `end` cave, which it then
    returns. Then it returns the `next` unexplored path leading to the `end` cave. By default, small caves can only be
    explored once. This can be changed by supplying the `extend_one_small=True` argument to the constructor, in
    which case one small cave can be explored up to two times in a single path.

    Attributes:
        self.cave_system : `CaveSystem` that is being explored
        self.entrance : `list` of `Cave` objects. Serves as the first, imutable part of every path return by this
            instance of `CaveIterator`
        self.extend_one_small : `bool`, tracks whether one small cave is allowed to be eplored up to two
            times.
        self.to_explore : `list` of `Cave` objects that that can be reached from the last cave in `self.entrance`,
            that is, the current cave. This list is popped one by one throughout iteration.
    """

    def __init__(self, cave_system, entrance, extend_one_small=False):
        """
        :param cave_system: `CaveSystem` to be explored
        :param entrance: `list` of `Cave` objects that serve as the first, immutable part of every apth generated by
        the iterator
        :param extend_one_small: `bool`, if `True`, one small cave can be explored twice in a path. Default is
        `False`; every small cave can be explored no more than once.
        """

        # Copy the initializing arguments
        self.cave_system = cave_system
        self.entrance = entrance
        self.extend_one_small = extend_one_small

        # Produce the `self.to_explore` attribute by creating the `list` of every `Cave` that is connected to the
        # final one in `self.entrance`. The iterator will explore each of the caves in reverse order.
        # If the 'end' cave is one of such cases, move it to the beginning of the list, making it the last cave to be
        # explored. Note that `Cave.joints` is a `list` of `str`, thus the `cave` in the list expressions is a `str`
        self.to_explore = [self.cave_system.caves[cave] for cave in self.entrance[-1].joints]
        names_to_explore = caves_to_names(self.to_explore)
        if 'end' in names_to_explore:
            end = self.to_explore.pop(names_to_explore.index('end'))
            self.to_explore.insert(0, end)

        # Even when `extend_one_small` is toggled, the 'start' cave, which is technically a small cave, can still only
        # be explored once, upon entrance, which should have happened by now, so it chould never be explored by the
        # `CaveIterator`
        if 'start' in names_to_explore:
            del self.to_explore[names_to_explore.index('start')]

        # If `extend_one_small` is not toggled, exclude every small cave from `self.to_explore` if it's already listed
        # in `self.entrance`.
        if not self.extend_one_small:
            self._exclude_small_caves()
        # Otherwise, see of there's a small cave that is already listed twice in `self.entrance`. Only then get rid of
        # small caves in `self.to_explore` that are also listed in `self.entrance`
        else:
            for cave in self.entrance:
                if not cave.big and self.entrance.count(cave) > 1:
                    self._exclude_small_caves()
                    logger.debug(f"{cave.name} triggers exclusion of small caves")
                elif not cave.big:
                    logger.debug(f"{cave.name} is allowed twice")

        # These two are used by `self.__next__()`, the first one keeping track of the currently explored cave, and
        # the second one generating a nested `CaveIterator` for the cave currently being explored.
        self._current_path = []
        self._current_iterator = None

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Return the actual iterator.
        :return: `iterator`
        """
        return self

    def _exclude_small_caves(self):
        """
        Exclude every small cave from `self.to_explore` that has already been listed in `self.entrance`.
        :return: `None`
        """
        for cave in self.entrance[:]:
            if not cave.big and cave in self.to_explore:
                self.to_explore.remove(cave)

    def __next__(self):
        """
        Produces the next path (`list` of `str` names in the order in which they are explored) for the current
        `CaveSystem` that satisfies supplied conditions
        :return:
        """

        logger.debug(f"entrance: {caves_to_names(self.entrance)}, to explore: {caves_to_names(self.to_explore)}")

        # If there're no caves left unexplored and the current cave has been fully explored, stop iteration
        if not self.to_explore and not self._current_iterator:
            raise StopIteration

        # If the last cave left unexplored is the 'end' cave, append that cave to `self.entrance` and return it as the
        # discovered path
        if self.to_explore and self.to_explore[-1].name == 'end':
            self.entrance.append(self.to_explore.pop())
            return_path = caves_to_names(self.entrance)
            return return_path
        # If no cave is currently being explored, create an iterator for the last cave in `self.to_explore`
        if not self._current_iterator:
            self._current_path = self.entrance[:]
            self._current_path.append(self.to_explore.pop())
            self._current_iterator = CaveIterator(self.cave_system, self._current_path, self.extend_one_small)
        # Try returning a new path going through `self._current_path`. If no such path can be found, reset
        # `self._current_iterator` and try again by calling `self.__next__()` until it yields a path or stops iteration.
        try:
            return next(self._current_iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            self._current_iterator = None
            return self.__next__()


def flatten(x):
    """
    Flatten a list or a tuple
    :param x: multidimensional `list` or `tuple`
    :return: one-dimensional `list` of objects from the original `x` iterable
    """
    flattened = []
    for item in x:
        if isinstance(item, list) or isinstance(item, tuple):
            flattened.extend(flatten(item))
        else:
            flattened.append(item)
    return flattened


def caves_to_names(lst):
    """
    A simple function to produce a `list` of cave names (`str`) from a `list` of `Cave` objects
    :param lst: a `list` of `Cave` objects
    :return: a `list` of `str` cave names in the same order
    """
    return [cave.name for cave in lst]

# Read the input
with open('input12.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().rstrip()

# Split the data line by line and generate a cave system
puzzle = data.split('\n')
cave_system = CaveSystem(puzzle)

# This snippet of code lists every cave and its connections, for further debugging
if DEBUG:
    for cave in cave_system.caves:
        print(cave, cave_system.caves[cave].joints)

# Do the actual count
count = 0
for path in cave_system:
    count += 1

extended_count = 0
for path in cave_system(extend_one_small=True):
    logger.debug(f"{path}")
    extended_count += 1


print(f"When every small caves is explored no more than once, the number of paths is {count},\n"
      f"but when one small cave can be explored up to two times ina  single path, it's {extended_count}.")
```